# To whomever makes the per-site icons: Thank you

Tags: discussion, favicon

I've always been a fan of the unique icons made for [each community on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Is there a Stack Exchange employee who makes them? Or are they made by community members on each site?

Whoever made them, I want them to know that they did a fantastic job. I hope they know how much the Stack Exchange community appreciates the work that went into them.

[image: Various icons of Stack Exchange]

Comment: SE's design team does ask for general input from the community, but the actual design proper is all theirs.